# Cython early imports of libraries and comp/link in setup.py

Tags: cython, cythonize

I often cimport C libraries for use in my own Cython modules. Good recent examples are MPFR and GSL. I am however confused how Cython handles *.pxd files, and how I have to comp/link the Cython modules.

Let's say I have `someImports.pxd` which looks like this

```
cdef extern from "mpfr.h":
    ctypedef unsigned int mpfr_prec_t
    void mpfr_set_default_prec(mpfr_prec_t prec) nogil
```

To be able to use this in other modules, the **other** modules have to comp/link with the MPFR library. If I write a tiny wrapper function (even inline!) in `someImports.pyx`, then I don't have to do this.
I'm talking about basically the extra_compile_args and extra_link_args in my `setup.py`.

```
extensions = [Extension("someImports", ["someImports.pyx"],
                        extra_compile_args = ['-lmpfr','-lgmp'],
                        extra_link_args = ['-lmpfr','-lgmp']
                        ),
              Extension("useImports", ["useImports.pyx"],
                        extra_compile_args = ['-lmpfr','-lgmp'], # Need this when no wrapper function in someImports.pyx
                        extra_link_args = ['-lmpfr','-lgmp'] # Need this when no wrapper function in someImports.pyx
                        )
              ]
```

In `useImports.pyx` I just cimport the `someImports` and well, call the functions.
Seems to me this is slightly weird behavior, so I think I might be missing something.

The "full" test example can be found in a github https://github.com/oliverhaas/cython_lib_import

Comment: Very related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58162089/5769463. Your first variant translates more or less to a simple include (and then you need to link library otherwise the definition of the declared functions isn't available, case B in the linked answer) when you wrap the function in pyx-file and use its pxd, you  actually postpone the name-resolution until runtime and use the Cython-maschinery for that (case D in the linked answer).

Comment: Thanks for the comment (again, we met like 4 times now I think in the last weeks :) ). I only half understand your linked post for now, but it's nice to know how it works. As a rule of thumb: I probably should try to use case D if possible; small "wrappers" are useful anyway if something needs to be changed. Does this sound right to you, or would you recommend anything else?

Comment: I would recommend to wrap the functionality in a pyx file and expose it in pxd-file to be used other cython-extensions. This might be tedious, but makes the usage of the resulting wrapper very easy. Another thing you should keep in mind: linking static libraries to different extensions is problematic, as singletons are no longer singletons in this case, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/45372319/5769463